# Landscape table doesn't fit in the page

Tags: tables

I managed to create a landscape table but the problem it doesn't fit in the text width as shown below. Any idea to solve this problem. My code is provided below.

[image]

```
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering
          \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{My Results}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
    \textbf{FF} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{AA} & \textbf{BB} & \textbf{CC} & \textbf{DD} & \textbf{FF} & \textbf{GG} & \textbf{HH} & \textbf{II} & \textbf{JJJJ} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Ccccccccccc} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaaaa aaaaa}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aa aa aaaaaa}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaa}} & \textbf{aaaa} & \textbf{aa +} & \textbf{aa +} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaa}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaaa aaaaa}} & \textbf{aa +} & \textbf{aa +} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaa}} \\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaaaa} &       &       &       & \textbf{aaaaa} & \textbf{a-aaaaa} & \textbf{a-aaaaa} &       &       & \textbf{a-aaaaa} & \textbf{a-aaaaa} &  \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\\\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
    \midrule
    Aaaaaaa &    & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{22}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{33}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{44}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{55}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{66}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{77}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{88}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{99}} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: `\tiny`  or `\small` or whatever size fits ?

Comment: yup, I don't mind if the font is decreased a little bit as long as the whole table fits in the page

Comment: so just use that then, after \begin{table*}

Comment: What's the paper size, how wide are the margins, and what font and font size you you use?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it gave me a fatal error

Comment: @Mico the document class is \documentclass[12pt]{report}

Comment: @SMH Any particular fatal error?

Comment: You did the wrong thing then, but if you don't show any code or any error message no one can help.

Comment: the error is !pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file ecrm0600): Font ecrm0600 at 600 not foun
d
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: Your tex system is not set up correctly presumably you get the same error with a document that just looks like `\documentclass[12pt]{report}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\begin{document}\tiny hello \end{document}` if so you should ask a new question about that as it's unrelated to the subject line here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with reducing text size a little (`\small`) and reasonably shrinking space between columns (`\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{4pt}`), both changes are relatively unnoticeable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,multirow,lscape}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table*}[htbp]
  \centering\small
          \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{My Results}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
    \textbf{FF} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{AA} & \textbf{BB} & \textbf{CC} & \textbf{DD} & \textbf{FF} & \textbf{GG} & \textbf{HH} & \textbf{II} & \textbf{JJJJ} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Ccccccccccc} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaaaa aaaaa}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aa aa aaaaaa}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaa}} & \textbf{aaaa} & \textbf{aa +} & \textbf{aa +} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaa}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaaa aaaaa}} & \textbf{aa +} & \textbf{aa +} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{aaa}} \\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaaaa} &       &       &       & \textbf{aaaaa} & \textbf{a-aaaaa} & \textbf{a-aaaaa} &       &       & \textbf{a-aaaaa} & \textbf{a-aaaaa} &  \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\\\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
    \textbf{aaaaaaaa} & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 333333 & 444444 & 5555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10100 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
          & 000   & \textbf{1111} & 22222 & 33333 & 44444 & 55555  & 66666 & 77777 & 88888 & 99999 & 10.10 \\
    \midrule
    Aaaaaaa &    & \textbf{0000} & \textbf{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{22}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{33}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{44}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{55}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{66}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{77}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{88}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{99}} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it gave me this error:
!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file ecrm1095): Font ecrm1095 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Could you please help me in that?

Comment: @SMH Try adding this in preamble: `\usepackage{lmodern}`. Do you still get the error? Also, do you run the example separately, or you inserted it in a bigger document?